# Free and paid architecture drawing software

Tags: software-recommendation, open-source

What software is useful for designing buildings with accurate measurements?

I originally trained with AutoCAD a long time ago but haven't needed to use any modelling softwares since, I'm wondering if there is anything more suitable nowadays.

I'm looking for open source and paid softwares if possible, to research them a little more before I make my choice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is about architecture, not graphic design. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a wide variety of software out there for working with architectural visualization, with an even wider variety of design goals. What software you ultimately go with is going to depend heavily on what exactly *you* intend to use it for.

In general, architectural design software sort of falls on a spectrum from purely artistic software (IE: programs for creating realistic images or artwork based on design plans) to strict drafting software (IE: programs for making structural blueprints). I recommend that you look around at all the options before you decide to stick with any one software, but here are a few to get started:

Primarily Artistic:

- [Blender 3D](http://www.blender.org/) (open source)
- [3DS Max](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-3ds-max/overview)
- [Autodesk Maya](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-maya/overview)

Core Architectural Software:

- [AutoCAD Architecture](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-autocad-architecture/overview)
- [Building Design Suite](http://www.autodesk.com/suites/building-design-suite/overview)
- [Google SketchUp](http://www.sketchup.com/) (free)
- [Design Workshop](http://architecture.about.com/gi/o.htm?zi=1/XJ&zTi=1&sdn=architecture&cdn=homegarden&tm=356&f=10&su=p504.6.342.ip_&tt=3&bt=7&bts=8&zu=http%3A//www.artifice.com/free/dw_lite.html) (free)

Drafting Software:

- [AutoCAD LT](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-autocad-lt/overview)
- [Chief Architect](http://www.chiefarchitect.com/products/)
- [ViaCAD 2D/3D](http://www.punchcad.com/p-9-viacad-2d3d-v8.aspx) (inexpensive)

Any one of these programs will more than likely have all the tools you need to do just about anything for architectural design and modeling, but finding one that matches *your* particular plans will help ensure that you have the most freedom and power in what matters most to you.